Apple/iPhone app store problems - can't figure out
When trying to download an app the screen asks me to "Touch ID to Install", but there's no ID to touch or click on (?)
This happens to me at multiple places, not only the app store. Some versions of the app-store screen include a small keyboard icon at the left. Clicking on that, allows me to get around the problem, but the Apple app store doesn't have that icon, so I'm stuck right there. When I click on "settings," there's an option that says "Touch ID and Passcode". When I enter my passcode in response to that, a screen comes up that has a red fingerprint icon at the top. Just below that, it shows a menu labeled "USE TOUCH ID FOR". It contains the following 4 options which are all turned on (green): "iPhone Unlock", "iTunes & App store", "Wallet & Apple Pay", "Password Autofill". Below that, there's a second menu.
This happens to me at multiple places, not only the app store. Some versions of the app-store screen include a small keyboard icon at the left. Clicking on that, allows me to get around the problem, but the Apple app store doesn't have that icon, so I'm stuck right there. When I click on "settings," there's an option that says "Touch ID and Passcode".
When I enter my passcode in response to that, a screen comes up that has a red fingerprint icon at the top. Just below that, it shows a menu labeled "USE TOUCH ID FOR". It contains the following 4 options which are all turned on (green): "iPhone Unlock", "iTunes & App store", "Wallet & Apple Pay", "Password Autofill". Below that, there's a second menu   labeled "FINGERPRINTS," with 3 lines: "Finger 1","Finger 2", and "Add a Fingerprint". I haven't done anything with that.
Below that there are 2 blue (clickable, I assume) links labeled "Turn Passcode off" and "Change Passcode".
Then there's a single line saying "Require Passcode ... Immediatley >" and another line with a switch labeled "Voice Dial", which is turned on. Then there's a long list of switches, the majority of which are turned on. I undoubtedly gave you too much information, but I have no idea what you need.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Does your phone have a TouchID sensor?  That's what the dialog is referring to, it doesn't mean that there's some textual ID on the screen for you to click.

OP, it would really help to know what model phone and which version of iOS it's running. Please update your question.
